# Rails: Nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

The following path throws up an error:

```
 = link_to 'Subscribers', user_subscribers_path(current_user)
```

> undefined method `user_subscribers_path' for <#:0x007f9b240b3148>

I am not sure why.

I have defined my routes as follows:

```
  resources :users, :only => [:show, :index], :has_many => :subscribers, :shallow => true
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
rake routes does not show anything particularly useful. The only two lines with subscribers are:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index {:has_many=>:subscribers}
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show {:has_many=>:subscribers}
```

Comment: Can you do `rake routes` in your terminal and show us the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define resource subscribers in routes files as follows

```
resources :users do 
 resources :subscribers
end
```

this will create the needed path helper for your resource

For the shallow routes you can use

```
 map.resources :users, :shallow => true do |user|
  user.resources :subscribers 
 end
```

Comment: I want my routes to be shallow. I guess I would have to define shallow here?

Comment: and that seems to define routes like  new_subscriber GET/subscribers/new(.:format) subscribers#new - which is probably something I would not be interested since I am looking for nested routes ...

Comment: this will create nested routes, you can create shallow routes by passing :shallow=> true to helper. check this out http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/9/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-shallow-routes

Comment: worked. I simply added what you added above with the :shallow. I have marked your answer as fixed - would be great if you updated your answer with :shallow for future reference and other users. Thanks!